# Error installing Wine on 10.6.8

Tags: error, wine

I was installing [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) on 10.6.8 and got this error:

```
Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)

Error: Failed to install expat

Log for expat is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/main.log

Error: The following dependencies were not installed: expat expat flex gettext libiconv gperf libiconv ncurses ncursesw ncurses fontconfig freetype bzip2 zlib zlib freetype gnutls libgcrypt libgpg-error libtasn1 lzo2 pkgconfig glib2 autoconf help2man p5-locale-gettext perl5 perl5.12 perl5 perl5 m4 automake libtool pkgconfig readline jpeg jpeg lcms tiff tiff libpng libxml2 libxml2 libxslt mesa makedepend xorg-xproto py27-libxml2 python27 db46 gdbm openssl openssl python_select sqlite3 python27 xorg-dri2proto xorg-glproto xorg-libXfixes xorg-fixesproto xorg-libX11 xorg-bigreqsproto xorg-inputproto xorg-kbproto xorg-libXau xorg-libXdmcp xorg-libxcb xorg-libpthread-stubs xorg-xcb-proto xorg-util-macros xorg-xcmiscproto xorg-xextproto xorg-xf86bigfontproto xorg-xtrans xorg-libXi xorg-libXext xorg-libXi xorg-libXmu xorg-libXt xorg-libsm xorg-libice xorg-libsm xorg-libXcomposite xorg-compositeproto xorg-libXcursor xorg-renderproto xrender xrender xorg-libXinerama xorg-xineramaproto xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto xorg-libXxf86vm xorg-xf86vidmodeproto

Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.

To report a bug, see 


I checked out the log file and at the end of the file I saw this:


:error:configure Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)

:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)

    while executing

"$procedure $targetname"

:info:configure Warning: the following items did not execute (for expat): org.macports.activate org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install

:error:configure Failed to install expat

:notice:configure Log for expat is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/
_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/main.log
```

Comment: We need to see the first error in the expat log file

Comment: This? :info:configure checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
:info:configure See `config.log' for more details.
:info:configure shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_textproc_expat/expat/work/expat-2.0.1" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --disable-dependency-tracking --mandir=/opt/local/share/man " returned error 77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine can be a pain to compile. It can be easier to use precompiled binaries such as Wineskin: http://wineskin.doh123.com/ or Winebottler http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/.

Try those links and see how you get on.

Comment: I'll check them out. I've done it just fine before (compiling Wine), but I'll try those ones.

Comment: Thanks so much. I used WineBottler and that worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

To [install macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php) you first need to install Xcode to get a C compiler. That is the usual issue for

> error: C compiler cannot create executable

You can either get Xcode free from the App Store if you have Lion or [register as a developer](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/)

Comment: I have Xcode 4.1 installed.

Comment: and the Unix parts - is there gcc and ld in /usr/bin ?

Comment: Yes, gcc and ld are in /usr/bin.